# How to shuffle and ORDER BY column with where clause

Tags: mysql

MySQL table has totally 50 rows(records). There are two column. Column1 has a value for 10 records. Column2 has a value for 40 records. In the result, Column1 must come first then Column2. Column1 must be Shuffled with where clause like where Column1='1'. Then 15 records from Column2 (you can use here where clause if you want) must be ORDER BY DESC. Then the remaining records of Column2 must be shuffled. How to do?. any help please. I need query like.

```
Select * 
from mytable 
where column1='1' rand(), column2 
ORDER BY DESC limit 15, column2 rand();
```

Comment: You can't shuffle one column and not shuffle the rest.  You can order by.  But that's about it.  Each row is a unique object.

Comment: Sounds like homework? Is it?

Comment: just out of curiousity, how can 1 column have 10 records and the other 40?

Comment: I guess he means that `column1` has a value in 10 records, and `column2` has a value in the other 40 records.

Comment: Are you sure about the php tag? Since you seem to want a SQL only solution...

Comment: yes mr. Barmar is right

Answer (score 0):

Use a `UNION`

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT *
    FROM mytable
    WHERE column1 = '1'
    ORDER BY RAND()) AS t1
UNION ALL
    (SELECT *
    FROM mytable
    WHERE column2 != ''
    ORDER BY column2 DESC
    LIMIT 15)
UNION ALL
    (SELECT *
    FROM mytable
    WHERE column2 != ''
    AND column2 NOT IN (
        SELECT column2
        FROM mytable
        WHERE column2 != ''
        ORDER BY column2 DESC
        LIMIT 15)
    ORDER BY RAND())
```

Comment: the remaining 25 result of column2 must be shuffle

Comment: sir it is giving error. I put here my original error;select * from marriage where paid='1' ORDER BY RAND() UNION select * from marriageIncorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY

Comment: This query is used for testing: $sql="select * from marriage where paid='1' ORDER BY RAND() UNION select * from marriage";

Comment: Sorry, the subqueries need to be put in parentheses. And the random function in MySQL is `RAND()`, not `RANDOM()`. Try it now.

Comment: I used RAND() only. it is giving error. and I don't know how to subqueries need to be put in parentheses

Comment: It would help if you told me the error. Could you make a sqlfiddle I can test with?

Comment: What do you mean you don't knokw how to put the subqueries in parentheses? I put it in my edit to the answer.

Comment: sorry, see this query I used: $sql="select * from(select * from marriage where paid='1' ORDER BY RAND()) UNION (select * from marriage ORDER BY id DESC limit 10)"; and error is: select * from (select * from marriage where paid='1' ORDER BY RAND()) UNION (select * from marriage ORDER BY id DESC limit 10)Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: You're missing `AS t1` after the first subquery, like I have in the answer.

Comment: thanks lot sir, now it is working.  I will flag this answer after my complete code runs. and what is the meaning of AS  t1

Comment: It's an alias for the subquery -- just what the error message says is needed. This is basic MySQL syntax.

Comment: "derived table" is another name for subquery.

Comment: Thanks for your support.

Comment: ORDER BY id DESC is not working. The query is : $sql="select * from (select * from marriage where  paid='1' ORDER BY RAND()) AS t1 UNION (select * from marriage ORDER BY id DESC) LIMIT 10";

Comment: Please make a sqlfiddle with sample data.

Comment: Try changing `UNION` to `UNION ALL`. That may keep it from reordering when it combines the results.

Comment: I changed UNION to UNION ALL. But result is same as it was before.

Comment: I can't help you without a sqlfiddle.

Comment: sorry sir. I am hearing about sqlfiddle at first time here. I don't know about sqlfiddle. just now opened sqlfiddle.com. I am trying there what I have to do? please help some more.

Comment: Put the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements in the left box to create the data. Click Build Schema to load it. Then put the query in the right box.

Comment: in the left box I put my complete database then I clicked build schema. the result was schema ready. then I put the query in right box that: $sql="select * from (select * from marriage where paid='1' ORDER BY RAND()) AS t1 UNION (select * from marriage ORDER BY id DESC)"; The result was You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '$sql="select * from (select * from marriage where paid='1' ORDER BY RAND()) AS t' at line 1

Comment: You can't put PHP code in sqlfiddle. It's just plain SQL.

Comment: The schema is missing at that link, there's nothing in the left box. The query in the right box shouldn't be a PHP script, it should just be `SELECT` like in my answer.

Comment: ok again I give you link. this is without php showed error: Table 'db_9_9eecb7d.marriage' doesn't exist

Comment: sorry this link is not working. how to give you link. just copy the URL or what?

Comment: if you have any mail id. please give me. I send my database.

Comment: I can't read that. I'm sorry, but if you can't put in the effort to learn how SQL and sqlfiddle works, I'm not going to spend any more time on this. It's your problem, not my responsibility.